# Mortgage Calculation

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have to calculate the maximum mortgage possible for a customer.

If it is a single application, the customer can borrow up to three times their salary plus any savings and investments they may have.

If it is a joint application, the customer can borrow 3 times larger salary and 2 times the smallest, also borrowing against any savings and investments.

In either case, the applicant is not allowed to borrow in excess of 90% of the purchase value of the property (including stamp duty and legal fees).

I have declared everything and done out the code, yet every time I calculate the max amount they can borrow, it comes up as 0. My code is below if anyone can spot problems.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _  
        Handles btnMaxPossible.Click

    If rbtnSingleApp.Checked Then
        txtMaxPossible.Text = Val((intSalary1 * 3) + intInvestments + intSavings)
        txtMaxPossible.Text = intMaxPossible
    ElseIf rbtnJointApp.Checked Then
        txtMaxPossible.Text = Val(intSalary1 * 3 + intSalary2 * 2) + _
            intInvestments + intSavings
    End If

    txtMaxPossible.Text = (intProperty + intLegalFees + intStampDuty) * 0.9

End Sub
```

Comment: Winforms? Webforms? WPF?

Comment: Did you notice you set `txtMaxPossible.Text` twice, to different things?

Comment: Either twice or three times.  Quality.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are initializing `intProperty`, `intLegalFees`, and `intStampDuty`. I suspect that these are their default values, i.e. 0.

Answer (score 0):

I have revised your logic as follows:

1) If the join app button is checked, then perform the joint calcs; otherwise perform the single calcs

2) Determine the max personal amount separately, then take the minimum of the max personal amount and the max property amount.

3) Remove the Val statements and use tostring

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMaxPossible.Click

    Dim MaxPersonalAmount As Integer

    If rbtnJointApp.Checked Then
      MaxPersonalAmount = (intSalary1 * 3) + (intSalary2 * 2) + intInvestments + intSavings
    Else
      MaxPersonalAmount = (intSalary1 * 3) + intInvestments + intSavings
    End If

    Dim MaxPropertyAmount As Integer

    MaxPropertyAmount = (intProperty + intLegalFees + intStampDuty) * 0.9

    txtMaxPossible.Text = Math.Min(MaxPropertyAmount, MaxPersonalAmount).ToString()

End Sub
```